# Performing math operations on very large numbers in Perl

Tags: perl, types, numeric

I have a case where some values in a data file have 64 bit wrap around which makes them very large, like, `18446744073709551608`.

So I have to perform a subtraction from 2^64. I tried this using the simple

```
2^64 - 18446744073709551608
```

But I guess this number is too large and don't get the actual answer 8. What do I need to do to perform this substraction.

Comment: `2^64` is bitwise or; `2**64` is two to the power of 64

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [`bignum`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) pragma:

```
use bignum;

print 2**64 - 18446744073709551608;
```

This should properly print `8`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that bignum is just a layer that makes all constant numbers automatically Math::BigFloat or Math::BigInt objects.  If you only want this for some numbers, you can either specify the `use bignum;` in a restricted scope, add `no bignum;` in places, or explicitly use `Math::BigFloat->new('your constant')` (or BigInt) to make particular numbers and the results of any operations involving them big.

Answer (score 0):

```
use bignum ;

print 2**64 - 18446744073709551608 ,"\n" ;
```

in perl language , ^ = ** , mod = %
good luck !

Comment: How is this different from @CanSpice answer?