# Why does Perl modulo operator work with large integers using bignum but not Math::BigInt?

Tags: perl, biginteger, modulo

I tried the following in a Perl script:

```
$b = 19999999999999999 % 10000000000000000;
print "$b\n";
```

It incorrectly outputted `0`.

Then I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620054/performing-math-operations-on-very-large-numbers-in-perl) saying to use `bignum`:

```
use bignum;
$b = 19999999999999999 % 10000000000000000;
print "$b\n";
```

It correctly outputted `9999999999999999`.

But `bignum` just converts all integer constants into a Math::BigInt.  So I tried the following which should be the same as using `bignum`:

```
use Math::BigInt;
$b = Math::BigInt->new(19999999999999999) % Math::BigInt->new(10000000000000000);
print "$b\n";
```

But that incorrectly outputted `0`.  Am I doing something wrong with Math::BigInt?

Comment: Works ok for me on both 64bit and 32bit Perl 5.26

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it on a 64-bit Perl and it worked fine, so I thought it would break on a 32-bit Perl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're still using native Perl numbers first and then converting them to `Math::BigInt` objects. Try this instead:

```
my $x = Math::BigInt->new('19999999999999999') % Math::BigInt->new('10000000000000000');
```

Quoting from [`perldoc Math::BigInt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt#Input):

> Input given as scalar numbers might lose precision. Quote your input to ensure that no digits are lost:
>
> ```
> $x = Math::BigInt->new( 56789012345678901234 );   # bad
> $x = Math::BigInt->new('56789012345678901234');   # good
> ```

(Also, don't use `$b` outside of `sort` and similar routines.)